# nested domain object not current, refresh() doesn't seem to work?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain model consisting of houses, owners and agents.

houses belong to owners, and owners have an agent.

I am able to assign an agent to an owner as follows:
house.owner.agent = [some user]

I can't seem to get house.owner  instance to recognize that the owner object has been updated, despite excessive flushing and refreshing.  It feels like I should be able to just say house.owner.agent = [some user] and then just house.save() but none of that seems to be sufficient.

Snippet from my bootstrap

```
     def house1 = new House(address: '2215 Manley Street', 
         sqft: 1750, acreage: 3.5d, owner: owner1, bedrooms: 3)
    house1.owner.agent=testUser1
    house1.save(flush: true)
    house1.owner.save(flush: true);

    house1.refresh()
    house1.owner.refresh()
    house1.owner.agent.addToActiveNegotiations(neg);  //fails, agent==null
```

Checking values in the debugger after setting a breakpoint at the last line in this snippet I see the following:

[image]

What's weird about this is that when I inspect the value of house.owner.agent the value is null, but when I look at the same domaiin object, separately retrieved, both objects have the same id, but one has agent = null, and the other 1 has the assigned user.  It seems like refreshing something ought to solve that problem, but I refereshed both house itself and house.owner just previous to the statement with the breakpoint but I still seem to have a stale object version in house.owner.

An explanation of this behavior appreciated.

Comment: try adding a House.withTransaction { } block around the bit in Bootstrap

Comment: adding codes from your model would help in answering.